# how to reposition layers on rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My tableView cells have a gradient layer

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
    gradient.colors = 
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85 green:0.85 blue:0.85 alpha:1] CGColor],
     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.82 green:0.82 blue:0.82 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    [cell.contentView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Which, when rotating obviously remain in the initial dimensions until i call

`tableview.reloadData`

I wonder if there is a more sophisticated approach than this.

The same goes with the NavigationController which has an image at the center,

```
UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
UIImageView *logoimageview = 
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
 CGRectMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.width / 2 - logo.size.width / 2, 
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height / 2 - logo.size.height / 2, 
            logo.size.width, logo.size.height)];

[logoimageview setImage:logo];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:logoimageview];
```

so the image does not reposition itself at rotation, and I'm not aware of any "refresh" method for the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

I have to warn you that I didn't test this, but I would expect it should work when you set the autoresizingMask. For the table view cell:

```
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

For the logo image view:

```
logoimageview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```